# Token Card Details iFrame - Server error 5003

Tags: php, opayo

I've inherited this project where the user's credit cards are saved via the Sagepay token card details `iFrame`. The token used is retrieved through the `3.0 protocol`.

The `form iFrame` is loading fine as you can see here: 
[image]

But when I try to submit a test card, it fails with `Server error 5003: Internal server error.`
[image]

I can't really debug this as everything is happening on the Sagepay side and the error is so broad.

Any ideas of why this could be happening?
Thank you!

Comment: You have given us absolutely no details on this, we don't even know if this is targetting the test or live version of SagePay. Your best bet is to ask SagePay, if this is the test site, that thing breaks all the time.

Comment: It is the test environment. Sorry, forgot to mention.  On the sagepay website says to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, they don't take part here unfortunately, just email support@sagepay.com

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a failure to reach your notificationURL (that usually manifests itself as a 5006 for a standard transaction, but is 5003 when registering a token).

Make sure your notificationURL is externally accessible, isn't using a port number (Sage Pay will only communicate over http/https default ports 80 / 443), and all your firewalls are open - I think test notification posts originate from IP  195.170.169.29 if that helps.